# How do I find the value a user is search for while he is still typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JavaScript:**

```
var array = [
    ['shoe', 1],
    ['shirts', 2]
];

$('input#item').keyup(function()
{
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('#value').html('value from array');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" />
<br />
Value: <span id="value"></span>
```

I want to find the value of the item the user is searching for **while he is still typing**.

**Example:**

a) When the user types `s`, it should output `1`, because it's the first value in the array.

b) When the user types `shi`, it should output `2`, because it matches `shirts`.

c) If there is no match it should output `no match`.

**Note:**
I want to keep the structure of the array, if possible.

Comment: hi friend, you should use an autocomplete plugin

Comment: What's the complication? You just have to loop through the array in response to the event. Regarding the event, I'd recommend `keypress` rather than `keyup`. `keypress` is fired repeatedly in case of key repeat, `keyup` only happens at the end when the key is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why, just loop through the array ...

```
var array = [
    ['shoe', 1],
    ['shirts', 2]
];

function findValue(array, value) {
    for (var i=0, ii=array.length; i<ii; i++)
        if (array[i][0].substr(0, value.length) == value)
            return array[i];

    return false;
}

$('input#item').keyup(function()
{
    var 
    value = $(this).val(),
    match = findValue(array, value);

    $('#value').html(match === false ? "no match" : match[1]);
});
```

didn't test it tho

Comment: there was a small bug in it (compared to array[i] instead of array[i][0] and output was match instead of match[1]). fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input#item').keypress(function()
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    var result = 'no match';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][0].indexOf(value) != -1) {
            result = array[i][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    $('#value').html(result);
});
```

Comment: almost right, but indexOf is not really what the OP describes he wants.

Comment: If he always wants it at the beginning of the string, he can change `!= -1` to `== 0`, he didn't specify it so I assumed he wants it anywhere in the string; nothing wrong with using `indexOf` to achieve it though.